# Cisco BGP Prefix Lists

Tags: bgp, acl

One of the benefits to Cisco's prefix lists is less CPU consumption over standard ACL`s. However I'm unable to find any further details.

So my questions is - why are prefix lists more efficient in terms of CPU over standard ACLs?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix-list significantly improves the performance (especially when you have long filters) over access-list. It is mainly because:

- Prefix-list is a tree struture and is not scanned sequentially, with each branch of the free serving as a test. Therefore, it makes decision much faster.
- Access-list is evaluated sequentially line by line until a match appears.